# Зачем нужен IServiceProvider

Tags: c#, .net-core, dependency-injection, сервисы

Существует такой тип в .NET как `IServiceProvider`. Его описание в официальной [документации](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.iserviceprovider?view=netcore-3.1#remarks) очень расплывчато:

> This interface is implemented by a class or value type that provides a service to other objects.
>
> The GetService method of this interface obtains the object that provides the service.

Я знаю, что этот тип используется в ASP.NET и при создании кастомного XAML расширения.

Но где ещё может использоваться этот тип? Можно ли ему найти свой применение в каких-либо других областях, как на продакшене, так и просто для себя? Да и какая вообще логика в использовании типа как аргумента метода `GetService`?

Comment: Это так называемый IoC-контейнер или DI-контейнер. Просто не рассказать. Вам надо прочитать книгу Внедрение зависимостей в .NET Марк Симана. Кажется, можно найти и в электронном виде, и на русском.

Comment: ниже в описании приведены ссылки на классы, реализующие этот интерфейс, для этих классов приведены примеры использования

Comment: Это жалкая попытка Microsoft заткнуть дыры в кривом дизайне своих фреймворков (ASP.NET, EF) и своей реализации DI.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov а что, у кого-то есть дизайн лучше?

Answer (score -1):

`IServiceProvider` это интерфейс позволяющий вам использовать внедрение зависимостей в ваш код.

Как правильно написал @Mark Shevchenko для полного понимания хорошо почитать книжку " Внедрение зависимостей в .NET".

Но в целом это работает так.

Например у вас есть класс, который зависит от данных находящихся в каком-то хранилище, доступ к которому осуществляется через какие-то промежуточные классы.
При обычном программировании он выглядит примерно так:

```
    class MsSqlDataAccessor : IDisposable
    {
      public DbDataAccessor() {/*тут логика инициализации*/}
      public IList<MyCoolEntity> GetAll()
      {
         //тут много кода специфичного для вашей бд.
      }
// Тут реализация IDisposable
    }
    
    class Summarizer 
    {
      public Summarizer() {/*тут логика инициализации*/}
      public GetSum()
      {
        using(var dataAccessor = new MsSqlDataAccessor()){
          var result = 0;
          foreach(var item in dataAccessor.GetAll()){
            result += item.Sum;
          }
        }
      }
    }
```

Если у вас возникает необходимость протестировать такой код в юнит-тестах, то вам необходимо создать дополнительную базу данных и использовать ее в тестах.
Если вам нужно использовать другую базу данных или web-сервис в качестве источника данных, в зависисмости от настроек, вам нужно будет добавлять if/else в каждое место где создается экземпляр MsSqlDataAccessor, что бы создать экземпляр правильного класса.
Это очень сильно усложнит код.

Что бы упростить жизнь используется `IServiceProvider` и `IServiceCollection`. `IServiceCollection` используется для определения списка доступных сервисов. `IServiceProvider` используется для извлечения необходимых вам сервисов из коллекции.
Пример с теми же классами.

```
    public interface IDataAccessor : IDisposable
    {
      IList<MyCoolEntity> GetAll();
    }
    
    class MsSqlDataAccessor : IDataAccessor
    {
      public DbDataAccessor() {/*тут логика инициализации*/}
      public IList<MyCoolEntity> GetAll()
      {
         //тут много кода специфичного для вашей бд.
      }
// Тут реализация IDisposable
    }
    
    class MockDataAccessor : IDataAccessor
    {
      public DbDataAccessor() {/*тут логика инициализации*/}
      public IList<MyCoolEntity> GetAll()
      {
         var result = new List<MyCoolEntity>();
         result.Add(new MyCoolEntity()
         {
           Sum = 100;
         });
         result.Add(new MyCoolEntity()
         {
           Sum = 200;
         });
         return result;
      }
// Тут реализация IDisposable
    }
    
    class Summarizer 
    {
      private readonly IServiceProvider _serviceProvider;
      
      public Summarizer(IServiceProvider serviceProvider) 
      {
        _serviceProvider = serviceProvider;
        /*тут логика инициализации*/
      }
    
      public GetSum()
      {
        using(var dataAccessor = _serviceProvider.GetService<IDataAccessor>()){
          var result = 0;
          foreach(var item in dataAccessor.GetAll()){
            result += item.Sum;
          }
        }
      }
    }
```

А где-то в инициализации приложения, скорее всего в Startup.cs или специально выделенном классе есть такой код:
`Services.AddScoped<IDataAccessor, MsSqlDataAccessor>(); // Здесь Services - экземпляр класса реализующего IServiceCollection`

```
А в юнит-тесте есть такой код:
var services = new ServiceCollection();
services.AddScoped<IServiceProvider, MockDataAccessor>()
var summarizer = new Summarizer(services.BuildServiceProvider());
var result = summarizer.GetSum();
Assert.Equals(300, result);
```

Это позволяет протестировать код без работы с реальной базой.

**Update:**

Основными причнинами применения `IServiceProvider` является создание коротко-живущих объектов, обычно реализующих IDisposable, либо создание громоздкого и редко-используемого объекта.

Однако, как верно указал в комментариях @PavelMayorov, более удобным, с точки зрения поддержки, является передача в конструктор не `IServiceProvider` а непосредственно используемых интерфейсов или фабрик. Например в приведенном выше примере можно сразу передать `IDataAccessor`, либо определить интерфейс:

interface IDataAccessorFactory {
IDataAccessor CreateInstance();
}

Сделать реализации для использования в Production и в коде Unit теста и использовать данные реализации при наполнении ServiceCollection.

Это позволит видеть все зависимости в конструкторе, хотя, для сложной логике может привести к разрастанию сигнатуры конструктора.

Comment: Зачем мне громоздить скопище классов с приставкой `Service`, если можно использовать банальный полиморфизм, т. е. `IDataAccessor accessor = new MockDataAccessor();`. А ваше решение задачи похоже на костыль. Походу придётся читать ещё 1-у книжку...

Comment: и да, не `Summaizer`, а `Summator`)

Comment: ещё, что тут означает «зависимость»?

Comment: Вы очень милый человек и Вам так приятно отвечать. :) Но к сожалению я не могу уделить этому достаточно времени. Почитайте книжку. Она интересная. :)

Comment: Вот не надо внедрять IServiceProvider в конструкторе, не учите плохому!

Comment: @PavelMayorov почему внедрение IServiceProvider в конструктор (например контроллера) это плохо? Понятно, что можно внедрять и сами сервисы, и даже непосредственно в методы контроллера, но чем конкретно плох вариант внедрения провайдера? Вот [тут](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/extensions/dependency-injection-guidelines#transient-limited-lifetime) это даже вроде как рекомендовано (само собой для конкретного кейса/кейсов).

Comment: @Anatol этот вариант плох тем, что скрываются конкретные зависимости, в итоге нужно выискивать по коду какие именно зависимости нужны классу. По ссылке предложено внедрять IServiceProvider не от хорошей жизни, а потому что в стандартном контейнере не реализован паттерн внедрения фабрики.

Comment: @PavelMayorov На самом деле, никто не мешает сделать свой интерфейс и реализацию фабрики и передавать ее в конструктор. Но вопрос был именно при IServiceProvider. Если вы можете предложить  свой ответ на исходный вопрос, не стесняйтесь его написать. Буду рад проголосовать за него.